# Android NDK Eclipse CDT won't allow me to use substr method of string

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, substring, eclipse-cdt

Even a simple code like this gives the error

```
string test= "hello";
string part = test.substr(2, 3);
```

Invalid arguments Candidates are: **stlpmtx_std::basic_string,stlpmtx_std::allocator> substr(?, ?)**

Even casting to size_t did not not help
    string part = test.substr((size_t)2, (size_t)3);

But both pieces of code working when running it as a console application using gcc 4.6 on Linux.
But when using Androind NDK it gives me the error.

If I close the file in the editor and close Eclipse, and then open Eclipse and build the project it compiles. But if I have the file open it throws up the error.

I am using APP_STL:= stlport_static in the Application.mk make file

Yes I did include <string>

Edit:  I  just looked at the times of .so file, it seems to be compiling even though Eclipse is showing the errors.

Comment: Did you include `<string>`?

Comment: yes I did include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I need to have to have stlport system include folder in the Paths and Symbols section of project properties -> C/C++ General

```
path_To_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/system/include
```

I only had the

```
 path_To_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
```

Comment: It's much easier to work on hybrid Android projects with the ADT bundle. For example, it autodicovers the include paths for you.

Comment: I am sure I have installed the ADT bundle

Comment: The latest versions of ADT don't expose "Paths and Symbols" for the Android NDK toolchain.

Comment: I am not going to update ADT and break something, so if they don't expose it how does Eclipse know where to find it